# Does a .NET SqlDataReader object use a database cursor, or the whole result set is loaded into RAM?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a sample code of using the `SqlDataReader`:

```
// Working with SQLServer and C#
// Retrieve all rows
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT some_field FROM data";

using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

I mean I want to understand whether there is the same mechanism when retrieving data from database in a while-loop (in case of `SqlDataReader`) as it does when working with the SQLite.

```
// working with SQLite and Java
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
      // do what ever you want here
   } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: The connection is a stream and the SqlDataRead reads from the stream.  The size and type of stream determines the amount of memory.  A large database will take time to get entire results so amount of memory used can vary significantly.

Comment: @jdweng Does SqlDataReader object use a db Cursor for reading that stream?

Comment: What do you mean by "db Cursor"? You seem to have a very specific question but it is not clear what you are concerned about.

Comment: @SeanLange I've updated question's description as you suggested.

Comment: I don't get your question at all. Both pieces of code get a result set and iterate over that result set row by row.

Comment: A SQL Server Cursor is a very specific SQL feature, which is different from a normal result set.  They may seem similar, but they're not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no cursor on the server side unless your command is calling a stored procedure that uses a cursor.  The server is returning a plain-vanilla SQL result set, one row at a time, when you use a SqlDataReader.  Obviously, the data's got to be somewhere before you can read it, and that place would be buffer(s) that SQL Server and the drivers manage.

If you were to push this into using something like a Dataset, *then* all the rows would be in RAM at once.

Comment: I didn't know about buffer.
Great answer! Now I got it... :)

Comment: @Andrey-WD [here is a document from the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx) that goes in to details about how the data gets sent across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

While you use cursor which returns many dbsets you can obtain many result sets like that:

```
while (oSqlDataReader.HasRows)
{
  while (oSqlDataReader.Read())
  {
    // oSqlDataReader.Getdata...
  }
  oSqlDataReader.NextResult();
}
```